# get all values for key in json list file python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I can't iterate over a JSON file to get all values for a key. I've tried multiple ways of writing this with many errors.

```
# Import package
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Assign url of file: url
url = 'https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json'

# Save file locally
urlretrieve(url, 'wwmu-gmzc.json')


# Loading JSONs in Python
import json
with open('wwmu-gmzc.json', 'r') as json_file:
    #json_data = json.load(json_file) # type list
    json_data = json.load(json_file)[0] # turn into type dict

print(type(json_data))

# Print each key-value pair in json_data
#for k in json_data.keys():
#    print(k + ': ', json_data[k])
for line in json_data['title']:
    print(line)
#w_title = json_data['title']
#print(w_title)
for key, value in json_data.items():
    print(key + ':', value)
    #print(json_data.keys('title') + ':' , jason_data['title'])
```

The current version of this code only gives the first line of the file:

```
<class 'dict'> 1 8 0 release_year: 2011 actor_2: Nithya Menon writer: Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, & Suba  locations: Epic Roasthouse (399 Embarcadero) director: Jayendra title: 180 production_company: SPI Cinemas actor_1: Siddarth actor_3: Priya Anand
```

Corrected code below and accounts for missing keys:

```
# Loading JSONs in Python
import json
with open('wwmu-gmzc.json', 'r') as json_file:
    content = json_file.read()
    json_data = json.loads(content)

print(type(json_data))

for json_i in json_data:
    try:
        print(json_i['locations'])
    except:
        print('***** NO KEY FOUND *****')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading only first data in the dataset.

```
with open('wwmu-gmzc.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file) # Input is list of dict. So,load everything

for json_i in json_data:
    print(json_i.get('your_key', 'default_value'))
```

Comment: this works but getting "KeyError: 'locations'" on some keys, so i'm guessing that the data is dirty causing it. Now i'll have to do something so it ignores/alerts when there is no key in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because the data your are fetching is actually a list. To read each item in the list (each item is a key-value pair) you can do.

```py
# Import package
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import json

# Assign url of file: url
url = 'https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json'

# Save file locally
urlretrieve(url, 'wwmu-gmzc.json')


# Loading JSONs in Python
with open('wwmu-gmzc.json', 'r') as json_file:
    content = json_file.read()
    json_data = json.loads(content)


for item in json_data:
    print('======')
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(key + ':', value)
```

Comment: i tried this but then could not get it to give me only the values for a specific key. thanks. <class 'list'>
=====
release_year : 2011
actor_2 : Nithya Menon
writer : Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, & Suba 
locations : Epic Roasthouse (399 Embarcadero)
director : Jayendra
title : 180
production_company : SPI Cinemas
actor_1 : Siddarth
actor_3 : Priya Anand
=====
release_year : 2011
actor_2 : Nithya Menon
writer : Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, & Suba 
locations : Mason & California Streets (Nob Hill)
director : Jayendr